# When a zero dimension point strikes a 2D plane, does ¨one side¨ of the point touch the surface of the plane or the entire point?

Tags: visualization

I am having a bit of trouble visualizing a zero dimension point bouncing off a wall like a billiards ball. The main reason I am having trouble with this is that a billiards ball has a side that is hit, depending on the side it bounces a specific direction away from a wall; a zero-dimensional point does not have sides and therefore will not have the directional input from being hit by the wall. Where would the point go if it doesn't have this directional input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ideal, perfectly rigid models for the wall and the billiard ball, they also touch at just a point and your visualization would also fail.

In both situations, the interaction is modeled as an instantaneous force, or, better, an *impulse* (change of momentum) **perpendicular to the wall** taking place at the collision. This way the speed along the wall remains unaltered by the collision (no force in this direction, since we ignore friction) while the speed perpendicular to the wall has its sign reversed (in a conservative, fully elastic collision), what gives you the "law of equal angles" or "law of reflection".

Answer (score 1):

There is no "one side" of an infinite small point. Either the point is within the 2D plane, or it is not.

Still, in theory you could define a scenario where a point-like particle bounces off a two dimensional wall. But then you would wait until the coordinates of the particle are within the 2D plane of the wall and then just flip the sign of its momentum.

In reality, forces (most likely electro-magnetic forces) would act before a point-like particle (an electron for example) reaches a wall. So even point-like particles in reality would hit the wall with "one side first" and bounce off before they reach the coordinates of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

> The main reason I am having trouble with this is that a billiards ball has a side that is hit, depending on the side it bounces a specific direction away from a wall

Think instead of the plane.  This point mass contacts the plane, and then is elastically reflected back, due to the resistance of the wall.  As long as you assume they represent physical objects, where the point cannot cross the plane (you can still assume it can deform it, though usually we consider it extremely stiff), then the ball should still bounce back.

It doesn't even need to restore *all* the energy.  As long as we assume the plane resists the penetration of the point mass; you can model the collision.

Just like in a billiards ball, movement parallel to the plane does not have to change (substantially), so when you bounce, it is like a "reflection", where the sign is changed only in the direction perpendicular to the wall.